# Catch all exceptions from a thread in Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to catch exceptions caused from any statement in an activity class so that I can prevent any crash. Testing all possible scenarios that the app may be used with is not possible. I would like to give an alert dialog or a textbox with a button within the app to report the issue but do not want the app to crash. So is there a way to do this?

I tried Throwing Exception at class level by using a constructor but that did not help. Try Catch cannot be done to every statement so what can be a good anti crash solution that can catch exceptions throughout whole of activity class?

Comment: "Testing all possible scenarios that the app may be used with is not possible." - I don't think that has to be true.

Comment: "a good anti crash solution" fixing the bugs leading to the `RuntimeException`s would be a good start. Catching exceptions is one thing, actually recovering meaningfully from them in any general way is basically impossible.

Comment: @JoeC I have been testing the app for many scenarios but it would be good idea to maintain better record of errors from within the app and prevent an crash which may be caused by one element which may not be necessary.

Comment: Caveat: the only reason you'd ever want to do this is generate a log, *not* to prevent the crash. OutOfMemoryException usually indicates a serious bug, and NullPointerException *always* indicates a bug. These exceptions simply shouldn't happen under *any* circumstances whatsoever in production code. Keep in mind that exception handling is to deal with exceptional cases, not to cope with bugs in the code.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I understand your point about the mentioned exceptions should be checked at development point but there are tons of devices with different API and RAM available and there can be crashes for other exceptions. There can be crashes due to some unchecked scenario which I wish to keep track of by pushing them on my server. Its generally not a great User Experience to see a crash.

Comment: That's true - crashes *are* a bad user experience. It may be tough to avoid in all cases, though, even with a global exception handler, though, because odds are not all of them will be recoverable, and it may be very difficult or impossible to determine in your exception handler which ones you can recover from (or which action you should take). For example, it's a little unclear what you'd do in the exception handler to recover from an Out of Memory Error, especially if it wasn't your app's fault. Once that happens, your best bet might be to take a long and send it off for analysis...

Comment: ... and then to fail as gracefully and as "un-annoyingly" as possible (unless it's one of the cases you've determined is recoverable from).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this create a `ExceptionHandler` class and collect crash record..

```
 public class ExceptionHandler implements
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final Activity myContext;
    private final String LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";

    public ExceptionHandler(Activity context) {
        myContext = context;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
        exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
        StringBuilder errorReport = new StringBuilder();
        errorReport.append("************ CAUSE OF ERROR ************\n\n");
        errorReport.append(stackTrace.toString());

        errorReport.append("\n************ DEVICE INFORMATION ***********\n");
        errorReport.append("Brand: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.BRAND);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Device: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.DEVICE);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Model: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.MODEL);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Id: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.ID);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Product: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.PRODUCT);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("\n************ FIRMWARE ************\n");
        errorReport.append("SDK: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.SDK);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Release: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        errorReport.append("Incremental: ");
        errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
        errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);

        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, CrashActivity.class); //start a new activity to show error message
        intent.putExtra("error", errorReport.toString());
        myContext.startActivity(intent);

        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(10);
    }
}
```

Now in your MainActivity initialize the ExceptionHandler using:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helpful but I am wondering where is the `CrashActivity.class` ?

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin `CrashActivity.class` is your custom activity where the error log is passed as intent. In this class you can get the error log from the bundle and show it in a textview or send the log to server etc..

Answer (score 1):

From main thread, in onCreate() for example

```
Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```